# Execution time for C++ Functions contradict

Tags: c++

I am have a main function that calls two user defined functions. Both the functions perform the same task( in this a simple selection with a selectivity factor of 50%) in a different way(using if else in one function and without if else in another function). I measure the execution time of both functions.

```
    int main()
    {
     clock_t t;
     period=clock();
     func1();
     period=clock()-period;
     print period

     period=clock();
     func2();
     period=clock()-period;
     print period
   }

   void func1()
   {
    int A[100000],B[100000],in=0;
    for (i=0;i<100000;i++)
    {
      A[i]=i;
    }
    for (i=0;i<100000;i++)
    {
      if(A[i]==3)
      B[in++]=i;
    }
   }
```

Func2 is similar to this except i replace the if by  a non-branching statement.

When i execute the program, which function am calling first is taking more time. In above case, func1 is taking more time. If i call func2 first followed by func1 , then func2 is taking more time. I really dont understand the logic behind this.

Can anyone explain please.

Comment: Probably because the first implementation brings the input set into the cache. Hard to tell without seeing actual source, though.

Comment: Ok 2 minutes... I will edit the question with source

Comment: @vinodc, your code is not compilable. If you post code following the guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, you might get some positive feedback.

Comment: what your test actually shows is that the things people think make a difference to performance usually don't, and the things that do make a difference are unexpected. At least you did a test, many people 'just know' whats slow and why and 'fix' it

Answer (score 0):

If `Func2` is the same as `Func1` except for the branch in the second loop, my guess is that for the first function called, the operating system has to commit pages for the stack, while the second function can just use the pages already committed.

Operating systems tend to only commit memory on demand, so that more programs can fit into physical memory. For a new thread, Windows commits (actually backs the virtual memory addresses with physical memory pages) the amount of stack specified in the executable headers. It then commits further pages of stack only when the process touches the page. It continues to do this until the specified reserve size is reached, after which it will generate Stack Overflow exceptions. The defaults used by Microsoft's `link.exe` are to reserve 1MB of virtual address space for each stack, and commit a single page (4kB).

When the process does touch the page, the processor tries to look up the virtual address in the Translation Look-aside Buffer. It won't be found - a TLB 'miss' - so it will then try to look it up in the process's page tables. The page table will contain an invalid entry, so it will raise a page fault exception.

The operating system's page fault handler looks at the page table entry and determines that this belongs to a thread stack, so it finds an empty page of memory, modifies its page frame database to mark that this page now belongs to this process, modifies the page table to point to the new page, then dismisses the exception. The processor restarts execution with the instruction that faulted.

Processor exception handling is **slow**. A bunch of context information gets pushed onto the stack so the processor knows where to return to, the pipelines stall, the TLB may not have the OS code's location in it any more, the instruction and data caches likely don't have the OS code or data in them.

Assuming `int` is 32-bit on your compiler, you have 400,000 bytes in the first array and another 400,000 in the second. The first loop will generate (probably) 98 page faults to create the first array, then the second might generate a further fault to set `B[0]` to 3.

It can also depend on your compiler, operating system, and the compiler options. With large arrays declared on the stack like this, some compilers will generate a 'stack probe' at the beginning of the function to ensure that the stack is committed properly. Windows requires that the process commit its stack page-by-page in the correct order, so Microsoft's compiler inserts a call to the `_chkstk` function at the start of the function. This deliberately reads from each stack page in turn, so that the OS commits the page. This is documented in [KB 100775](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100775).

Linux [reportedly just commits stack pages on-demand](http://xania.org/200808/hacking-about-with-stacks), and doesn't require that the program commits pages in the right order.